# FFMPEG - skipping the decode of some keyframes causes delay?

Tags: objective-c, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to decode some keyframes in my app [1 second away from each other], and noticed that if I don't decode ALL keyfrmaes on the way, I get a weird delay in the decoded frames [the created pixel-buffer shows an old frame].

Any ideas why this might happen?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK without decoding key frames (I frames) you cannot decode predicted frames which comes between two I frames (P and B) because these just a differences from last I frame and uses it as main source. This is why there is a delay.